# append component and access child componet's value in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am a novice for vue.js. I want to ask:
How can I append component repeatly? If the appended component is a child component, how does the child component transfer the value to the parent component, and how does the parent component identify which child component transfered the value?

Comment: Thank you Mate, but i'm still curious about the last question: how does the parent component identify which child component transfered value?especially when I use V-for to loop a component.

Comment: Thanks again,you solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Could you please vote up one of my comments then?

Comment: I am pleased to vote up, but i can't find the the small up arrow to the left of a comment,only a flag being.

Comment: You are right, I added them as an answer and deleted them as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append components repeatedly with v-for directive:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

The child components communicate with parents by emitted events or the v-model directive. About the former you can read here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html, about the latter here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

You can pass an id or an index together with the emitted event or you can pass the $event.target, there are several possibilities depending on why you exactly need to identify the element.